# Disable input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

for some reason I want to disabled an input text and for this I use this sample code :

```
$('#id').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Is there any way to disabled an input text without use attribute disabled of input text, I mean for example use css or other ways?

In fact I want an input text act like a disabled one without change it attribute?

With Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<input id="myTxt" type="text" onfocus="this.blur()"/>
```

Or by JS:

```
$('#myTxt').focus(function(){
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it through CSS (unless you do something very complicated like hide the input and put a disabled-looking rectangle in its place).  However, this will disable the input without changing the attribute:

```
$("#id").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: when use prop disabled='' add to element. I don't want to add it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" value="" />
```